# GDB resetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: gdb

Running GDB 7.4-2012.02 on Ubuntu and am experiencing weird behavior that I can't duplicate on other platforms.

```
bash$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=my_path
bash$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH2=my_path2
bash$ gdb
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.02-0ubuntu2) 7.4-2012.02
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>.
(gdb) shell echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

(gdb) shell echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH2
my_path2
```

As can be seen, GDB is resetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH but none of the other exported variables. Why is it doing this? Is there some setting I don't know about which causes this? My ~/.gdbinit is empty and the behavior persists even when using `gdb -n`.

Additionally, after exiting back to the login shell:

```
bash$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
my_path
bash$ $SHELL -c 'echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
my_path
bash$ $SHELL
hi from .bashrc
bash$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
my_path
```

So I don't think my startup scripts are the issue.

Comment: Check your shell startup files.There are similar reports which proved wrong: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15190 and http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9011. So, GDB runs the program like `exec $SHELL -c program`. Could you repeat their test: 1) run `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` 2) run `$SHELL` 3) run again `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? And add your results to your question?

Comment: skwllsp, see updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So I don't think my startup scripts are the issue.

Yes, they *are* the issue (I know for a *fact* that GDB does not mess with your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment).

**Update:**

Startup scripts were not the issue after all.

After some debugging, user2601195 discovered that the following variables were all getting unset: `GCONV_PATH`, `GETCONF_DIR`, `HOSTALIASES`, `LD_AUDIT`, `LD_DEBUG`, `LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT`, `LD_DYNAMIC_WEAK`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_ORIGIN_PATH`, `LD_PRELOAD`

These are environment variables that [glibc considers *insecure*](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=sysdeps/generic/unsecvars.h;hb=HEAD), and unsets for setuid binaries. It turned out that in fact the `gdb` being invoked was suid-root:

```
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 5975928 Mar 15 2012 /usr/bin/gdb
```

which explains the problem.

Comment: I SURELY used single quotes. I am not *that* inexperienced. Also see the lines below that one, where I enter the sub-shell and check the variable from within the sub-shell. I also know for a fact that GDB is not supposed to mess with that variable, hence why I cannot reproduce the behavior on other machines. Thanks for a non-answer. I would down-vote but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @user2601195 Is your *login* shell the same as `$SHELL`?

Comment: @user2601195 I've updated the answer with debugging suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Looking at the strace out, did a grep for "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" and only turned up the line executing /usr/bin/gdb, NOT the line invoking bash. So the variable wasn't passed to the subshell from gdb.

I tried running gdb in gdb but it can't find breakpoints for setenv or unsetenv (gdb wasn't built with debug symbols...).

Comment: @user2601195 In order to set breakpoint on `setenv` does *not* require any debug symbols, but does require that `libc.so.6` is already loaded. Try running to `main`, *then* set the breakpoints.

Comment: Okay. I got the two breakpoints for setenv LINES and COLUMNS as the child gdb was starting, but no break for any unsetenv. However, looking at the strace for that I saw that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH was only being passed to the parent gdb and not the child. Anyway, later I tried setting the breakpoints as pending before starting the child gdb. i.e. "b unsetenv; start; c" and I actually DID get a break on a bunch of unsetenvs, including GCONV_PATH, GETCONF_DIR, HOSTALIASES, LD_AUDIT, LD_DEBUG, LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT, LD_DYNAMIC_WEAK, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_ORIGIN_PATH, LD_PRELOAD and a bunch of others.

Comment: I have no idea from where the unsetenvs are being called. Just tried the same procedure it on another system and got no breaks for unsetenv.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is GDB might be configured for a system wide init file that telling it to unsev those variables, but I don't know where the init file resides.

Comment: @user2601195 Re: I have no ide where `unsetenv`s are being called. -- that's why you are running GDB under another GDB: just do `where` when the breakpoint is hit. The environment variables being unset match variables that glibc unsets for setuid binaries. Is your copy of gdb on this system an suid binary? If so, that's the answer!

Comment: That seems to be the case! "-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 5975928 Mar 15  2012 /usr/bin/gdb". Thank you.